# Excel-DNA: Create WPF user control to be displayed after click on ribbon button

Tags: c#, wpf, excel-dna

I'm coding some c# code in excel through excel-dna.
I've managed to create a custom ribbon with some buttons to execute methods.

However, I would like to create a WPF window/pop-up/user-control that would appear after the user click on a button.

I've searched but I could not find anything that would help me.
I've found this link:

https://groups.google.com/g/ExcelDna/c/dr1UiE3o3VU

```
Dim wpfWindow As System.Windows.Window = New System.Windows.Window
wpfWindow.Content = New UserControl1 'Your design-time wpf usercontrol
wpfWindow.Show()
```

But I cant figure out a way to make it work.
So far I got this:

```
public void PressMe()
{
    var activeSheet = _excel.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;
    activeSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Hello, World!";
}
```

I've created a new WPF user control, named WpfScreen.xaml, which I would like to be shown when the method PressMe() is run. This WPF UC only has a text in it (testing reasons).

Can someone give me a help on how I can show this WPF UC?
The project is of type Class-Library with net6.0.

I would like to apply the logic MVVM with this. I've done MVVM with a simple WPF project with netframework, but I am not being able to do that here with Excel-DNA, Class-library and net6.0.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: UC needs a window parent, and unless I'm mistaken you can't have that in a library. What we did in [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) is that we hosted the WPF user controls in a WinForms dialog with an ElementHost. Works pretty well.

Comment: So have you actually tried opening the window from PressMe()?

Comment: I got it :) sorry for the delay.